# Print with delay a string in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to print a String in a TextView on my AndroidApp with some delay between each character. The String is pi and I want to simulate the fact that the app is computing it live. I tried to add some delay with a sleep function so as not to flood the TextView with too many request too quickly, to no avail as it still doesn't work :(

The string is:
String pi_value = "3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117";

```
public void printWithDelays(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)
            throws InterruptedException {
        String pi_temp = "";
        TextView pi_text_holder = findViewById(R.id.pi_text_holder);
        pi_text_holder.setText(pi_temp);
        for (char ch : data.toCharArray()) {
            pi_temp.concat(String.valueOf(ch));
            pi_text_holder.setText(pi_temp);
            unit.sleep(delay);
        }
    }
```

If you had an idea I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty good solution. It works well.

https://ssaurel.medium.com/create-a-type-writer-effect-on-android-4dc8f2ccada6

Answer (score 0):

You can use kotlin flows or Rxjava and use debounce operator.
You can convert string to list of characters and use Observables. fromArray(list_of_characters) then apply debounce operator.
e.g

```
Observables. fromArray(list_of_characters).debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe({
  textView.text = it
},{
})
```

Answer (score 0):

public void printWithDelays(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)throws InterruptedException {

String pi_temp = "";

TextView pi_text_holder = findViewById(R.id.pi_text_holder);

for (char ch : data.toCharArray()) {

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pi_temp.concat(String.valueOf(ch));
                        pi_text_holder.setText(pi_temp);
                    }
                },delay);
    }
```

}

Comment: It sets the pi_temp = " " alright but doesn't display String.